# Pagination with Jquery not working

Tags: visualforce, jquery, datatable

Following is my code where in i wanted to do pagination for Datatable.

```
<apex:page id="page" standardController="Error_Log__c"  extensions="errorLogController_Check_MDSR" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="true" >
  <apex:slds />

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>  

<!--
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.TableJS}"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.TableCSS}"/>
-->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#DataTableBlock1').DataTable();
        } );
      </script>

  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="Interfaces" id="pgblock">
      <apex:pageBlockSection >
        <apex:inputField value="{!interfaceDate.CriteriaStartDate_MDSR__c}" label="Date" styleClass="slds-input">
          <apex:actionSupport action="{!pageReload}" event="onchange" reRender="interfacepb,errorLogs"/>
        </apex:inputField>
        <apex:inputField value="{!interfaceDate.Interface_Type__c}" label="Interface Type" styleClass="slds-input">
          <apex:actionSupport action="{!pageReload}" event="onchange" reRender="interfacepb,errorLogs"/>
        </apex:inputField>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!errWrpList}" var="recs" id="interfacepb" styleClass="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer" >
      <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Interface Name</apex:facet>
        <apex:commandLink value="{!recs.interfaceName}" id="interfaceName" action="{!errorLogs}" reRender="errorLogs">
          <apex:param name="testParam"  value="{!recs.interfaceName}" />
          <apex:param name="recordCountSelRec"  value="{!recs.recordsCount}" />  
        </apex:commandLink>
        <!-- <apex:actionSupport action="{!errorLogs}" event="Onclick" reRender="errorLogs"/>                        -->
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!recs.recordsCount}" headerValue="Number of Transaction"/>      
      <apex:column value="{!recs.sendRecordSum}" headerValue="Sent Records" />
      <apex:column value="{!recs.failedSum}" headerValue="Failed Records"/>
      <apex:column value="{!recs.processedRec}" headerValue="Processed Records"/>
      <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Interface Type</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!recs.interfaceType}"/>
        <apex:param name="setFieldSet"  value="{!recs.interfaceType}"/>
      </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock> 
    </apex:form>    
  <apex:pageBlock title="Error Logs" id="errorLogs">
    <apex:pageblocktable style="overflow:Auto;" value="{!errorLogsRec}" var="record" rendered="{!IF( interfaceTypevar=='Batch Integration',true,false)}" id="DataTableBlock1">
      <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Error_Log__c.FieldSets.Batch_Interface}" var="fieldAPIName">
        <apex:column value="{!record[fieldAPIName]}"/>
      </apex:repeat>

    </apex:pageblocktable>
    <apex:Datatable value="{!errorLogsRec}" var="record" rendered="{!IF( interfaceTypevar=='Real-Time',true,false)}" id="example">
      <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Error_Log__c.FieldSets.RealTime}" var="fieldAPIName">
        <apex:column value="{!record[fieldAPIName]}"/>
      </apex:repeat>
    </apex:Datatable>
    <apex:Datatable value="{!errorLogsRec}" var="record" rendered="{!IF( interfaceTypevar=='Lot Batch',true,false)}" id="DataTableBlock2">
      <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Error_Log__c.FieldSets.Lot_Batch}" var="fieldAPIName">
        <apex:column value="{!record[fieldAPIName]}"/>
      </apex:repeat>
    </apex:Datatable>        
  </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:page>
```

Comment: So...what's not working, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are not able to access the apex:pageblocktable.

That's because, Id's in Salesforce are auto-generated for visualforce components.

To access components in jQuery, one of the easiest method is to use [`ends with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

Try following code.

```
$("[id$='DataTableBlock1']").DataTable();
```

**Note**: Try using HTML table instead of `apex:pageBlockTable` as the datatable's styling might get messed up.

Comment: See also: [Best Practices for Accessing Component IDs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)